# Performance testing of meteor based app

Tags: node.js, meteor, jmeter

I was asked to do a quick benchmark load test on one of our meteor based node app.

I am very well used to jmeter. But, the app doesn't show up any http/REST based calls and instead it uses DDP protocol.

So, I think jmeter is not feasible. Can anybody suggest some tools?

I have looked in to [phantomas](https://github.com/macbre/phantomas) and [Felt](https://github.com/kidk/felt) but couldn't get a clear picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your meteor app is using Websocket, this blog should help you get your test working:

- https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/cloud-based-jmeter-websocket-testing/

It mentions the most up to date websocket plugin for jmeter.

Comment: Meteor had implemented DDP on top of SockJS. SockJS does emulate WebSockets. I tested with above and figured out that WebSocket sampler from above URL is not of much help.

Answer (score 1):

According to [DDP protocol specification](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/ddp/DDP.md) it may use either [SockJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sockjs) or [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) as underlying transport.

In case of WebSocket I believe you can use [WebSocketSampler](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler) plugin, see [WebSocket Testing With Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter) guide.

Regarding SockJS - you might try out [TCP Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#TCP_Sampler) in combination with [Wireshark](https://wireshark.org/) - an ultimate sniffer tool to capture the packets.

If you still looking for an alternative tool - check out [The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/), it comes with the [TCPProxy](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/tcpproxy.html) which is capable of recording raw TCP packets.